# Bad date format from google sheets in app

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have Imported HTML in Google Sheets downloaded a table from a site with some texts and dates. Google Apps Script transfers JSON data to a mobile app and listsview lists it. The table with the text is OK, but with the dates, the cell that is in the sheet is 23.3.2019 as 2019-03-22T23: 00: 00: 000Z. When I change the format of the cell to text, the date will change to 43547 for it, but I need the date format 23.3.2019 for the app.

change cell format in sheets

```
strong textvar ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("my_url");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Items');
function doGet(e){
var action = e.parameter.action;
if(action == 'getItems'){
return getItems(e);
}
}
function getItems(e){
var records={};
var rows = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() -1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  data = [];
for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
var row     = rows[r],
    record  = {};
record['itemName'] = row[2];
record['brand']=row[3];
record['date']=row[4];
data.push(record);
}
records.items = data;
var result=JSON.stringify(records);
return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}



enter code here
```

Comment: log the content of `row[4]` I think that would be `2019-03-22T23: 00: 00: 000Z` which means you would have to do a custom conversion on `row[4]` before assigning the value to `record['date']` For conversion, I'd suggest **moment.js** or some library, if you can write a small custom converter, no harm.